# Vagrant how to get exit code from Windows command over SSH?

Tags: windows, ssh, cmd, vagrant, exit

I am using a Vagrant VM with Windows 7 for an automated build process.

If I SSH directly into Windows, I can see that `%ERRORLEVEL%` is being set:

```
$ vagrant ssh
> false
> echo %ERRORLEVEL%
1
```

However, if I send an SSH command to Windows directly, Vagrant does not use the exit code:

```
$ vagrant ssh -- cmd.exe /C 'false'
$ echo $?
0
```

Is there a way to pass the Windows `%ERRORLEVEL%` variable from the command executed via Vagrant SSH back to my host shell? I'm hoping that the solution doesn't involve redirecting the variable into a file.

Answer (score 0):

what happens if you try:

vagrant ssh -- cmd.exe /C exit 1

just thinking cmd.exe /c is opening up a new command prompt and false is within that rather than returning anything outside like exit with value would!

Comment: ok so testing the right hand side I can confirm works - i.e. cmd.exe /c exit 1 as just wrapped that into a bat file and called it redirecting the errorlevel to a file without vagrant.

That leaves the issue towards vagrant side and whilst I have deployed with many tools vagrant isn't one of them. 

I assume vagrant runs in system context which on windows does not have the user hive to load the path and locate cmd.exe if so could try c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c exit 1


Next step after that would be to create a bat fileyou can call dumping to a txt (this is for troubleshooting only)